# What are non-locking design patterns?

Tags: design-patterns, locking

Today I came across a technology jargon for the first time.

> Non-locking Design Patterns

Could someone more learned give more detail about it? Link to any existing article/knowledge base would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

They are probably talking about non-blocking algorithms. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm) is a good starting point.